# How do I sent a list to another form and edit its values in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a list that is declared with a structure:

```
public struct videoParts
    {
        public string fileName { get; set; }
        public float stopTime { get; set; }
        public float startTime { get; set; }

        public int videoId { get; set; }
    }

    public struct renters
    {

        public string code { get; set; }
        public int renterId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string comments { get; set; }
        public string pictureDir { get; set; }



        public string videoDir { get; set; }

        public string docDir { get; set; }

        public float totalTime { get; set; }

        public List<videoParts> video;

    }
```

I am populating that list from a Json file when I start the program, and use it as a Datasource in a listbox, which works fine. Using the renterId value to be passed when I click the listbox item. This also seems to work, the values passed are shown correctly in the new form:

```
 private void OnListBoxItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        renters selectedRenter = rentersList.Find(x => x.renterId.ToString() == id);
        Movie movieForm = new Movie(id,selectedRenter);
       
        movieForm.Show();
    }
```

However, the issue is now that when I change the selected renter on the movieForm, the value does not seem to get edited on the mainform. On the MovieForm:

```
public renters selectedRenter = new renters();
public Movie(renters _selectedRenter)
    {
         
        
        //read code and renter id
         
        InitializeComponent();


        //get List reference

        selectedRenter = _selectedRenter;
```

Edit button:

```
private void commentSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string comment = "";
        foreach(string line in commentBox.Lines) 
        { 
            comment = comment + line;
        }
        selectedRenter.comments = comment;
        
        MessageBox.Show(selectedRenter.comments);
    }
```

When I show the Messagebox the value is correct. However, the list on the mainForm is not being updated. It still holds the old value.

So, I have two questions:

1. How do I edit the list that is being used on the mainform, to include the edited values from the MovieForm?
2. How do I update the ListBox on the MainForm with the new data?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sounds like you want two way data binding.  `List<T>` does not raise events required for this to work as you'd expect.  Try using a `BindingSource` on top of the list or something else that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, however, when the code creates a new `Movie` form with… `Movie movieForm = new Movie(id,selectedRenter);` … ?... this looks odd in a sense that the posted `Movie` constructor shows only ONE (1) passed in value with … `public Movie(renters _selectedRenter)` … yet it is called passing in TWO (2) values… ? … is there another `Movie` constructor that takes two values that you are not showing?

Comment: I think @Zer0 gave the correct suggestion... you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in VideoParts and them use observable collections like ObservableCollection<VideoParts> in the view model